# Subsets with large symmetric difference

Tags: combinatorics

Let us assume I have a set of size $n$.
I want to find exponentially many subsets, such that, for **any pair** of subsets  $S,T$  It holds that $\left|S\triangle T\right|\geq\frac{n}{4}$.

Notes:

- I am yet to be convinced that such family of subsets exists.
- It doesn't has to be specifically $\frac{n}{4}$, but it has to be linear in $n$.
- I am not looking for constructive proof  (although it can be nice) showing that such a set has to exist is also enough (I was thinking maybe the probablistic method?).

Comment: This boils down to the construction of suitable codes and should be solved in E. Berlekamp, Algebraic Coding Theory (McGraw-Hill, New York, 1968).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the probabilistic method gives a quick proof of existence. Let $m$ be a natural number to be specified later, and let $S_1,\dots,S_m$ be independently and uniformly chosen from the subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Then
$$
P(|S_i\,\Delta\,S_j|\le n/4)=2^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n/4}\binom nk\le 2^{-n}\cdot 2^{H(1/4)n}=O(c^{-n})
$$
I am using [this bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Sums_of_binomial_coefficients) for the sum of the binomial coefficients. Here, $H(1/4)=(1/4)\log_2 (4/1)+(3/4)\log_2(4/3)$, and $c=2^{1-H(1/4)}$, but all that matters is the probability is exponentially decreasing as a function of $n$.

The expected number of pairs of subsets whose difference is at most $n/4$ is at most
$$
\binom{m}2c^{-n}.
$$
As long as $m\le \sqrt{2c^n}$, the expected number of bad pairs is less than $1$, so the probabilistic method successfully proves the existence of a collection $S_1,\dots,S_m$ where all pairs have distance more than $n/4$.

Comment: Thank you! the probabilistic method is so impressive, it can lead to some elegant results.